# How to directy use RenderTransform property of TextBlock

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, rendertransform

I understand I can rotate text like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="4:00">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

But how can I use the `RenderTransform` property of `TextBlock` directly like:

```
<TextBlock Text="4:00" RenderTransform="<How does this work?>"/>
```

to avoid the inner code?  Maybe a general tutorial for how this works would be good as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RenderTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) property is of type `Transform` which can mean many possible transform types. So you can`t assign it to some type that has some properties using just a string by default.
If you want to to conserve space though, you can define your RotateTransform in resources, and give it some key:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <RotateTransform x:Key="myRotateTransform" Angle="-90" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then just use it like that:

```
<TextBlock Text="4:00" RenderTransform="{StaticResource myRotateTransform}" />
```

This will work even better if you need to apply same transform to several controls too, because you can edit it in just one place.